# Bootstrap col-* not taking full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following **code:**

```
<div class="row row-space">
    <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <div class="row">
                <div>CHILD A</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <div class="row">
                <div>CHILD B</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, all `.row` divs take full width of parent outer div (as expected)
but the ones with `col-lg-12` or (`col-lg-6` + `col-lg-6`) are not taking the full width.

[image]

I am expecting the black boxes to be divided equally inside the red box. I am not applying any other styles to the HTML.

Comment: You sure your display has lg? You may need to use `col-md-6` instead.

Comment: Your `.col-lg-8` and `.col-lg-4` are inside a `.col-lg-6`. That `.col-lg-6` is only going to take up **half** of it's **parent** element. Be aware of nesting a `.row` directly inside of another `.row`. The `.row` class has a negative left and right margin. If you don't need that margin to offset the padding on the `.col-x-x` classes then use a plain old `<div>` or `<div class="col-x-12">`.

Comment: @hungerstar - If you look at nesting section in the given link: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting
the outer is col-sm-9, and inner ones are col-sm-6 and col-sm-6. Isn't that the same as what I have done? Parent is 6, and Inner ones are 8 and 4 (ie. 66% + 33% of parent)

Comment: @Mahesh I think your question wasn't very clear. It sounded like you wanted `.col-lg-8` and `.col-lg-4` to take up more space than the ancestor `.col-lg-6` would allow. As far as the black and red box issue, I don't see it on Chrome in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkak9vsz/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because their parent is `col-lg-6`, change to `col-lg-12`

See more about twitter-bootsrap grid [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

**UPDATE** -based on your updated as well

You have extra unnecessary markup. So see snippet below:

**Snippet**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row row-space" style="border: 1px solid red">
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div>CHILD A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div>CHILD B</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you look at nesting section in the given link: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting
the outer is col-sm-9, and inner ones are col-sm-6 and col-sm-6. Isn't that the same as what I have done? Parent is 6, and Inner ones are again 6 and 6

Comment: but that won't give the full width as you want. only the full width till `sm-9`  so yours at the moment is stretching the width of parent `lg-6`

Comment: I want only till parent full width. The RED BOX is row (full parent width (default 100% and "I have not mentioned any parent for that"), Now that is divided equally into two BLACK BOXES - {col-lg-6}. But from the attached image, you can see that it is not taking full width.

Comment: your `.row`is a grandparent then you have a `.col-lg-6`as a parent (son of `.row`) and as children you have again two `.col-lg-6` so you need to change the parent to `.col-lg-12`as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: I think there is a confusion. i have updated the structure to make it easy to understand. (Again thanks for the patience), so here there is not parent. Only .row (in RED which takes full width). So its children should be split equally to 6 and 6 columns. But that is not happening.
When i select Child A, the Bootstrap CSS applied is - @media (min-width:1200px) .col-lg-6 {width:40%'}. Shouldn't this be 50% ?

Answer (score 2):

add div container with class "container-fluid" with max-width: 900px;

for example
[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/reatlat/pen/JGeWPP)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row row-space">
  <div style="border: 1px solid red;" class="row">
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div>CHILD A</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black;" class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div>CHILD B</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container-fluid{
   max-width: 900px;
}
```